# Adding a video in DNN 9

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to add a video 2mb to my evoq web site. I get a error says video.mp4 - Extension not allowed. I have added mp4 to Allowable File Extensions part. I tried to add mp3 and i got the same error. I am trying to add the video to HTML Pro module. Do I need to select another module for adding videos?

Answer (score 1):

I have just done it. I went to Site Assets,uploaded the mp4. Then I clicked on the mp4 to get the url.

```
<video width="1056" height="594" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
<source src="https://test.windows.net/portals-sandbox2/1/Images/yourvideo.mp4?sr=b&si=DNNFileManagerPolicy&sig=0HYBH1YbfYIZr3h2tGgsiRMY66YW0YJsVtMF9EIMq0k%3D&timestamp=1526412367032" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```